# ajax does not return control under form for js after submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Bellow is my code for submitting form from list of categories. All buttons from list filling one form and it works ok before submitting form with ajax. 
After ajax submitting no one button can filling form again. 
I can filling form by hands again and send it again but if I want do this with JS (clicking buttons) then I get form with old data only.

```
$(function(){

   $("#categories span.addsubcategory").click(function(){
       $("#category-action").text("Add category: "+$(this).parent().children().eq(0).text());
       $("#parentcategoryid").val($(this).parent().attr('data-catid'));
       $("#ajaxaction").val('addsubdir');
       $("#categoryname").val('');
       $("#categoryname").prop("disabled", false);
   })

      $("#categories span.renamecategory").click(function(){
          $("#category-action").text("Rename category");
       $("#parentcategoryid").val($(this).parent().attr('data-catid'));
       $("#ajaxaction").val('renamedir');
       $("#categoryname").val($(this).parent().children().eq(0).text());
          $("#categoryname").prop("disabled", false);
   })

      $("#categories span.deletecategory").click(function(){
          $("#category-action").text("Delete category");
       $("#parentcategoryid").val($(this).parent().attr('data-catid'));
       $("#ajaxaction").val('deletedir');
       $("#categoryname").val($(this).parent().children().eq(0).text());
          $("#categoryname").prop("disabled", true);
   })

 $("#newcategory").submit(function sendCategory(){
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data: $("#newcategory").serialize(),
                success: function(response){
                        $("#categories .panel-body").html(response);
                        } ,
                error: function(){
                    alert("Data sending error");
                },
             complete: function(data) { 
                    $("#newcategory").find('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false); 
                    $("#adddir").modal('hide');
                 }
         });
          return false;
         }); 

});
```

Comment: Sorry, I have found decision. The buttons should be initialized again after ajax getting.

Comment: you need event delegation see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Delegate](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) all your click events

```
$("body").on("click","#categories span.deletecategory",function(){

  //code
});
```

Comment: $(function(){

     initButtons();
     
});

function initButtons(){
    $("#categories span.addsubcategory").click(function(){
       $("#category-action").text("Add category: "+$(this).parent().children().eq(0).text());
 .....

Comment: @ALexander what problem do you still have?

Comment: Thank you for help. It is ok now.